# How to: Git nesting versions/issues/tags

Tags: git, version-control

My question revolves around development flow and how to keep branch/sub-branch, issues, and releases organized.

I read the following answer from SO:

[confused about creating nested branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790561/confused-about-creating-nested-branches-in-git)

[How is a tag different from a branch? Which should I use, here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/how-is-a-tag-different-from-a-branch-which-should-i-use-here)

But I still don't see what's the best way to organize a project. For example:

If we have three issues that we are working on:

1. iss43(branch) - fixing banner bug
2. iss37(branch) - fixing checkout workflow
3. iss50(branch) - improving scroll bar

These three branches are all named after issues and are scheduled for release v1.2.3

In addition, we are working on two other issues, which have the following issues/branches:

1. iss20(branch) - fixing payment integration
2. iss55(branch) - UI improvements

These are grouped into release v1.2.4

So now the structure is:

```
Master
  -> iss43 (part of 1.2.3)
  -> iss37 (part of 1.2.3)
  -> iss50 (part of 1.2.3)
  -> iss20 (part of 1.2.4)
  -> iss55 (part of 1.2.4)
```

However, it would make more sense if the project would be organized as:

```
Master
-> v1.2.3
   -> iss43
   -> iss37
   -> iss50
-> v1.2.4
   -> iss20
   -> iss55
```

Since Git has no branch nesting, should the release be a branch/tag?
I.E.

`git checkout master
git branch release_v1.2.3
git checkout -b release_v1.2.3 v1.2.3
git branch iss43
git checkout iss43`

Which would make:

```
Master
    -> release_v1.2.3 (with tag v1.2.3)
      -> iss43 (issue branch)
      -> iss37 (issue branch)
      -> iss50 (issue branch)
```

Does this make sense or are there easier ways to track projects of small to medium size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You had it right the first time, your second approach is not the appropriate way.

In software development (moreover in git) you develop features and tag a version **when you release them**. Some feature scheduled on your roadmap for a specific version could take more time and end up in the next version (and the other way around)

In fact, you should have something like :

```
git branch -v

master
fix/iss43
fix/iss37
fix/iss50
fix/iss20
fix/iss55
```

You only bother about the tag (release) when you merge back one of the fix/* branch to master and decide to make a release.

Take a look at the following branching models : [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) or [github worklow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) (you might find better resources in english on google).